# Button in the form of polygon in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, user-interface, button, delphi-7, shapes

I need to make a button in the shape of rotated triangle (or let's say any polygon). Can anyone give any advice?

Comment: polygon of more than three line segments? concave / convex polygon? self intersected / non sef intersected polygon? please specify more clearly...

Comment: Not self intersected. Just a simple polygon. Like quadrilateral, with sides of different lengths and angles.

Comment: No need for concave also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the Win32 API `CreatePolygonRgn()` and `SetWindowRgn()` functions to create and assign an `HRGN` object to the Button's `HWND` handle.

Comment: This looks helpful, thanks. It doesn't look much like a button though, more like just a colored area. Is there a way to give it a button style (so that it has "pressed" look, when pressed).

Comment: @Tofig: TButton is a wrapper around the Windows Button control. If you want a button that is not rectangular, you have to do the "looks like a button" part yourself.